UWP DataGrid Scrollbar Issue: Unable to Scroll Using Touch on Touch Screen Devices
I'm developing a UWP app and I'm utilizing the DataGrid control from Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls to display data. While I can scroll using the mouse using both the scrollbar and its buttons, on a touch screen device, I can only scroll via finger gestures, and touching the scrollbar buttons or tracker does not work.
I am using a custom style for the scrollbar, but the issue persists even when reverting to the default style.
below is my custom style for scrollbar.
<Style x:Key="DataGridScrollBarStyle" TargetType="ScrollBar">
    <Setter Property="IndicatorMode" Value="TouchIndicator"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 4 10 4"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Grid x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="#FF1A428A" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" Background="White">

                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="RepeatButtonTemplate" TargetType="RepeatButton">
                            <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="Transparent" Margin="0">

                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalIncrementTemplate" TargetType="RepeatButton">
                            <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBackground}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForegroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E3;" Foreground="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForeground}" FontSize="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowIconFontSize}" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" />

                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalDecrementTemplate" TargetType="RepeatButton">
                            <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBackground}" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForegroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Root" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E2;" Foreground="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForeground}" FontSize="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowIconFontSize}" MirroredWhenRightToLeft="True" />

                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalIncrementTemplate" TargetType="RepeatButton">
                            <Grid x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF1A428A" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF1A428A" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <!--<FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E4;" Foreground="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForeground}" FontSize="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowIconFontSize}" />-->
                                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M 25 30 L 34 11 Q 40 0 29 0 L 11 0 Q 0 0 5 10 L 15 30 Q 20 40 25 30 Z"
                                    StrokeThickness="1"
                                    StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                                    Stroke="#FF1A428A"
                                    Fill="Transparent" Margin="4 5 0 5" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalDecrementTemplate" TargetType="RepeatButton">
                            <Grid x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonBorderBrush}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF1A428A" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF1A428A" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Arrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <!--<FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE0E4;" Foreground="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowForeground}" FontSize="{ThemeResource ScrollBarButtonArrowIconFontSize}" />-->
                                <!--Data="M 20 0 L 40 40 0 40 Z"-->
                                <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M 25 10 L 34 29 Q 40 40 29 40 L 11 40 Q 0 40 5 30 L 15 10 Q 20 0 25 10 Z"
                                    StrokeThickness="1"
                                    StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                                    Stroke="#FF1A428A"
                                    Fill="Transparent" Margin="4 5 0 0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalThumbTemplate" TargetType="Thumb">
                            <!--<Rectangle x:Name="ThumbVisual" Fill="Blue">
                        
                    </Rectangle>-->
                            <Border x:Name="ThumbVisual" CornerRadius="5" Background="#FF1A428A" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalThumbTemplate" TargetType="Thumb">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="ThumbVisual" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbFillPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbFillPressed}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ScrollBarThumbFillDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ThumbVisual" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <Grid x:Name="HorizontalRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="True">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect" Opacity="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="0" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackBorderThemeThickness}" Fill="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackFill}" Stroke="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackStroke}" />
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalSmallDecrease" Opacity="0" Grid.Column="0" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" IsTabStop="False" Interval="50" Margin="0" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalDecrementTemplate}" Width="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalLargeDecrease" Opacity="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" Interval="50" Template="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTemplate}" Width="0" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" />
                        <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb" Opacity="0" Grid.Column="2" Background="{ThemeResource ScrollBarPanningThumbBackground}" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalThumbTemplate}" Height="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" MinWidth="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1">
                            <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="HorizontalThumbTransform" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="{ThemeResource SmallScrollThumbScale}" TranslateX="0" TranslateY="{ThemeResource SmallScrollThumbOffset}" />
                            </Thumb.RenderTransform>
                        </Thumb>
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalLargeIncrease" Opacity="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" Interval="50" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" Template="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTemplate}" />
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="HorizontalSmallIncrease" Opacity="0" Grid.Column="4" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" IsTabStop="False" Interval="50" Margin="0" Template="{StaticResource HorizontalIncrementTemplate}" Width="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="HorizontalPanningRoot" MinWidth="24" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0">
                        <Border x:Name="HorizontalPanningThumb" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{ThemeResource ScrollBarPanningThumbBackground}" BorderThickness="0" Height="2" MinWidth="32" Margin="0,2,0,2" />

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="VerticalRoot" IsHitTestVisible="True">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect" Opacity="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="0" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackBorderThemeThickness}" Fill="White" Stroke="{ThemeResource ScrollBarTrackStroke}"/>
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="VerticalSmallDecrease" Opacity="1" Height="50" MinWidth="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" IsTabStop="False" Interval="50" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" Template="{StaticResource VerticalDecrementTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="VerticalLargeDecrease" Opacity="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="0" IsTabStop="False" Interval="50" Grid.Row="1" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" Template="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTemplate}" />
                        <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="2" Template="{StaticResource VerticalThumbTemplate}" Width="35" MinHeight="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" RenderTransformOrigin="1,0.5">
                            <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="VerticalThumbTransform" ScaleX="1.01" ScaleY="1.0" TranslateX="0" TranslateY="0" />
                            </Thumb.RenderTransform>
                        </Thumb>
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="VerticalLargeIncrease" Opacity="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsTabStop="False" Interval="50" Grid.Row="3" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" Template="{StaticResource RepeatButtonTemplate}" />
                        <RepeatButton x:Name="VerticalSmallIncrease" Opacity="1" Height="50" MinWidth="{ThemeResource ScrollBarSize}" IsTabStop="False" Interval="50" Margin="0" Grid.Row="4" Template="{StaticResource VerticalIncrementTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="VerticalPanningRoot" MinHeight="24" Visibility="Visible" Opacity="1">
                        <Border x:Name="VerticalPanningThumb" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="2" Width="2" MinHeight="32" Margin="2,0,2,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

How can I enable scrolling with the up and down buttons and tracker on touch devices?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
